# Is my file path for including an ejs partial correct?

Tags: filepath, ejs

My ejs header partial is in a directory below my index.ejs so the file structure goes:

> app/views/index.ejs
>
> app/views/partials/header.ejs

When I deploy locally with 'heroku local web' my static site works fine and I can navigate it. But when I try to deploy it online with 'heroku open' it errors:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/app/views/partials/header.ejs'.

```
    <!-- header -->
<% include partials/header %>
```

What can I do?

Link to [Github](https://github.com/tomtam6/tom-tam.git)

Comment: did my answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45294284/1946016

Answer (score 0):

Your partial folder starts with a uppercase 'P'
https://github.com/tomtam6/tom-tam/tree/master/views/Partials
and you have used lowercase 'p' in your code https://github.com/tomtam6/tom-tam/blob/master/views/index.ejs#L2